# URI formats are not supported exception

Tags: c#

I am new and I try to open a file.
Here is code:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
string filenamelocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Fix_DeltaPro.exe");
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(""+filenamelocation+"");
using (FileStream stram = File.Open(filenamelocation, FileMode.Open)) ;
```

But have little error : "URI formats are not supported. "
Help me please :)

Comment: I meant what does the string look like, can you log it (remove anything sensitive)?

Comment: file:\C:\Users|dimitar.grudev\documents\Visual Studio 2015' Projects\Helper\Helper\bin\Debug\filename.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CodeBase` is a Uri where the assembly was found. [This can a file `file://`, a web location `http://`, or other locations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/06/26/assembly-codebase-vs-assembly-location/).

In the instance of a file get the `AbsolutePath` for the Uri.

```
var codeBaseUri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(codeBaseUri.AbsolutePath);
var filenamelocation = Path.Combine(path, "Fix_DeltaPro.exe");

MessageBox.Show(filenamelocation);
using (var stream = File.Open(filenamelocation, FileMode.Open)) ;
```

Since the `CodeBase` can be loaded from difference places use the `Assembly.Location` to get the location where the assembly was loaded from disk.

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filenamelocation = Path.Combine(path, "Fix_DeltaPro.exe");

MessageBox.Show(filenamelocation);
using (var stream = File.Open(filenamelocation, FileMode.Open)) ;
```

See also:

- [`Assembly.CodeBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx)
- [`Assembly.Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)

Comment: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\dimitar.grudev\\documents\\visual%20studio%202015\\Projects\\Helper\\Helper\\bin\\Debug\\Fix_DeltaPro.exe'.

Comment: @spootles: That seems a reasonable location for where your executing assembly is. Are you sure that `Fix_DeltaPro.exe` is actually in the same place?

Comment: Yes, but i write with mistakes.Thank you so much it works!